# How to deal with name clash collections.Counter and typing.Counter?

Tags: python, collections, counter, type-hinting

The name `Counter` is defined both in `collections` (as a class) and in `typing` (as a generic type name).  Unfortunately, they are slightly different.  What is the recommended way of dealing with this?

Similarities and differences:

1. After `from collections import Counter`,

   1. you can call the constructor `Counter("foo")` to create a fresh `Counter` object;
   2. you can verify that it is subclass of `dict`: `issubclass(Counter, dict)` returns `True`;
   3. you cannot use it to declare a specific variant of `Counter`, e.g. `cnt: Counter[str] = Counter("foo")` raises `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` (the type hint fails)
2. After `from typing import Counter`,

   1. you can call the constructor `Counter("foo")` to create a fresh `Counter` object (actually, somewhat to my surprise);
   2. you cannot use it to verify that it is subclass of `dict`: `issubclass(Counter, dict)` raises `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`;
   3. you can declare a specific variant of `Counter`, e.g. `cnt: Counter[str] = Counter("foo")`.

In many cases 1.1 and 2.1 are good enough, so the choice of import doesn't matter.
But it seems you cannot have both 1.3 and 2.2 work with a single import. Of the latter two, the type hint is more important than the subclass check.
If you want to write type hints, then `from typing import Counter` suffices.
Though, I would find it clearer (and more in line with what is needed for some other types) if you write

```py
from collections import Counter  # to indicate that you want the implementation
from typing import Counter  # to indicate that you want to write type hints
```

(Note that the order matters.)

What if you want to have it all?
These are the options that I see:

1. Do

```py
from collections import Counter
import typing
```

and use `typing.Counter` to achieve 1.3.  Not nice, too wordy.

2. Do

```py
import collections
from typing import Counter
```

and use `collections.Counter` to achieve 2.2 (if needed; I needed it in teaching).

3. Do

```py
from collections import Counter as counter
from typing import Counter
```

and use `counter` to achieve 2.2.

4. Do

```py
from collections import Counter
from typing import Counter as Bag  # or Multiset
```

and use `Bag` (or `Multiset`) in type hints. (But this is bound to be confusing.)

5. Do (as suggested in a comment)

```py
import collections as co  # to access the class
from typing import Counter  # to access constructor and provide type hints
```

and use

1. either `co.Counter` or `Counter` as the constructor
2. use `co.Counter` as the class, e.g. `issubclass(co.Counter, dict)`
3. use `Counter` in type hints, e.g. `cnt: Counter[str]`

Is it then also to be recommended to do

```py
from typing import Deque
```

and use `Deque` as constructor, rather than `co.deque`? (I'd think/hope not.)

For other types (such as `defaultdict` and `deque`) this does not seem to be an issue:

```py
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from typing import DefaultDict, Deque
```

gives you all.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You can add another: `import collections as co; c = co.Counter('this is a good question')`

Comment: Why not use the full import?. typing.Counter and Collections.Counter are easily distinguishable and give better readability.

Comment: @MortenB I needed this in an educational setting, with students who just start to learn programming. It seems like an unnecessary complication, especially since such an approach is not needed for other types.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Python 3.9 you can do:

```py
from collections import Counter

c: Counter[str] = Counter()
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Counter

> Deprecated since version 3.9: collections.Counter now supports []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some more advanced cases for which this doesn't work, but you can create a subclass that inherits from both:

```
import typing
import collections

KT = typing.TypeVar("KT")

class Counter(collections.Counter, typing.Counter[KT]): pass

c: Counter[str] = Counter("foo")

print(isinstance(c, dict))  # True
```

Comment: But you don't want to throw this at beginning programmers, for something that with other types is not an issue.

Comment: @TomVerhoeff If I was designing it I wouldn't have separate `typing` classes at all, but I imagine there's some convincing technical reason that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of pain might be to settle for string-based type hinting. However, not every IDE will interpret it; PyCharm detects the type mismatch at the last line in this snippet, while VSCode believes all is well.

```py
from collections import Counter

mycounter: 'Counter[str]' = Counter('foo')

def func1(counter: 'Counter[str]'):
    pass

def func2(counter: 'Counter[int]'):
    pass

func1(mycounter)
func2(mycounter)
```

Comment: Certainly a good suggestion, and this would allow you to have a uniform approach. But it is rather pervasive, not mainstream, and in teaching it would feel artificial and unnecessary.